Definition of outward pointing vector fields (in Tu's Manifolds)
I am having some trouble resolving two ideas for outward pointing vector fields for manifolds with boundary in Tu's "Introduction to Manifolds (2nd Edition)." For the following, we let $M$ be a manifold with boundary $\partial M$. On page 254, Tu defines outward pointing vector fields in the following way:

We say that a tangent vector $X_p \in T_p(M)$ is inward pointing if $X_p \notin T_p(\partial M)$ and there are a positive real number $\varepsilon$ and a curve $c: [0, \varepsilon) \to M$ such that $c(0) = p, c(0, \varepsilon) \subset M^{\circ}$, and $c'(0) = X_p$. A vector $X_p \in T_p(M)$ is outward-pointing if $-X_p$ is inward pointing.

Later, Tu defines:

A vector field along $\partial M$ is a function $X$ that assigns to each point $p$ in $\partial M$ a vector $X_p$ in the tangent space $T_p M$ (as opposed to $T_p(\partial M).$ In a coordinate neigborhood $(U, x_1, \ldots, x^n) $ of $p$ in $M$, such a vector field $X$ can be written as a linear combination $$X_q = \sum_{i} a^i(q)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \bigg |_q, \quad q \in \partial M,$$

and finally

In terms of local coordinates, a vector $X_p$ is outward-pointing if and only if $a^n(p)<0$.

However, later (in problem 22.9), Tu asks us to show that the unit sphere, when thought of as the boundary of the unit ball, has an orientation form induced from the ball, using the fact that an outward pointing vector field is $$X = \sum x^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}.$$ Intuitively I get the picture, and agree that $X$ should be considered an outward pointing vector field. However, this vector field technically does not jive with the $n$th coordinate always being negative when you look at the patches (in fact, it is zero along the equator!). Is there a way to resolve this discrepency, or do we need to allow other local coordinates to have the property we have set aside for just $a^n$? In other words, is the $a^n < 0$ condition only valid when the last coordinate maps to the last coordinate in $\mathcal{H}^n$ (the closed upper half space), and do we need to be more careful when this doesn't happen?
